# How would I implement my own IntEnum in Python if one wasn't provided oob?

Tags: python, enums

I always struggle with Enum, IntEnum, etc and have to revisit the documentation several times each time I use this Python feature. I think it would be useful to have a more clear understanding of the internals.

For instance, why can't I use named arguments in this example?

```
class MD_Fields(IntEnum):
    ACCOUNT = (0, **identifier=True**)
    M_DESCRIPT = (4, False)

    def __new__(cls, value: int, identifier: bool):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj.identifier = identifier
        return obj
```

And of, course, the main question, how would do I pretend a Enum is a int? How do I tell Python that "SOME.ENUM" should be handled as if it was a 5?

Comment: Sorry. Just deleted the call out. Thanks @TimRoberts.
SO does say to share the question: "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook."
I figured sharing via SO would be even more adequate. Why is that bad?

Comment: You have the source code for IntEnum.  It's in "enum.py" in your standard library.  The reason your example doesn't work is that you are creating a simple tuple.  It's not creating an object. Tuples do not have named arguments.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks! That's a good information about the named arguments!

The source I found is just "class IntEnum(int, Enum):
    """Enum where members are also (and must be) ints"""

Comment: Yes, but your error is coming from `ACCOUNT = (0, identifier=True)`.  That has nothing to do with your class.  That's a simple tuple, and tuples do not have names.

Comment: There's no error @TimRoberts. Noticed I surrounded that with `**`. I was highlighting what I can't do. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score -1):

If `SOME.ENUM` is an IntEnum with the value `5`, then it *is* `5`:

```
>>> SOME.ENUM + 3
8
```

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, enums in python create overhead with very little value. Creating static class variables with the values you need is lightweight and semantically equivalent. And they maintain their type, which is what you needed.